# SQL query several lines in one row

Tags: sql-server-2008

I should accomplish the next query, I need a little help.  I would like to display the results in a dbgrid component in Delphi 7.

My table looks as follows:

```
Customer Name | Customer Adress | Site Name | Type
    CBA Ltd.  | Budapest      | K. city   | Retail
    CBA Ltd.  | Budapest      | K. city   | Wholesale
    CBA Ltd.  | Budapest      | K. city   | other
    CBA Ltd.  | Budapest      | C. City   | Retail
```

I would like to list CBA Ltd , Budapest, K. city in only one row. Budapest M. city would receive a new row. Ff I am right it is necessary to compare all three columns,  if all of three value are equal then to list them in one row.

Anyone can help me with this query?

Comment: This has nothing to do with Delphi. Your question appears to be related just to the SQL query that you run. You should rather focus on tags that desribes DBMS that you use. Now you have MySQL and SQL Server tags, is that really what you wanted ?

Comment: I am not perfect in English, please read well

Comment: I see that you want to show the results in `TDBGrid` in Delphi application but that's what query component assigned through the data source to the grid will do. You just need to run a proper query. That's your task for now.

Comment: MySQL and SQL Server are two entirely different database engines, with differences in the syntax for the SQL. You're not using both at the same time. The answer to how to do this type of query depends on the specific SQL dialect (engine) you're using, and you've not provided that information. Which one of the two are you actually using (MySQL OR SQL Server)? (You've already seen why it makes a difference when you couldn't use the `GROUP_CONCAT` in the answer you received. Please [edit] your question and decide what SINGLE database engine you're using.

Comment: Your edit is insufficient. Please [edit] **again** and provide the **specific SQL database engine** you're using. Once again, there are **different syntaxes and functions** between them, and knowing the **specific one you're using** makes a difference in the answer. If you don't want to provide that information, we can't help you. (SQL is a very generic term, and there is no generic answer that will fit all SQL dialects.)

Comment: I use microsoft sql server 2005 management studio express

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to group them, but which Type to show then? How about all of them?

```
SELECT customer_name, customer_addr, site_name, GROUP_CONCAT(type) AS type
FROM customers
GROUP BY customer_name, customer_addr, site_name
```

This would yield:

```
customer_name | customer_addr | site_name | type
    CBA Ltd.  | Budapest      | K. city   | Retail, Wholesale, other
    CBA Ltd.  | Budapest      | C. City   | Retail
```

Comment: Sorry for that, my bad... it was not a customer name, customer adress. I want to show customer_name, customer_adress and site_name only in one row. And if i got this query i want to list the types click on a customer name (cell click) in other dbgrid.

Comment: @Steve88, if these aren't the results you want, you should put the results you want in your question.

Comment: It will be the first result in a dbgrid.

Comment: 'GROUP_CONCAT' is not a recognized built-in function name.

Comment: @Steve88, then this is not [MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat), though you tagged it as such.

Comment: Than it will be a simple SQL. It is possible to do with it somehow?

Comment: select distinct customer_name,customer_adress,site_name from customertable group by customer_name,customer_adress,site_name something like that but i need a second query too